# Attempted read on closed stream

Tags: android, sockets, httpclient, inputstream

I get this exception when i scroll my ListView and fetch new data when last item in the list is reached.

This is the code to get new data:

```
public static String PostData(String url, String sa[][]) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    int n = sa.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(sa[i][0], sa[i][1]));
    }
    HttpPost httppost;
    try {
        httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(httppost);
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    try {
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine());
        String line = "0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append("\n" + line);
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //I get Exception here saying: Attempted read on closed stream
    }finally{
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

the **client** i used is:

```
private static DefaultHttpClient client = getThreadSafeClient();
```

of

```
public static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
            mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
    return client;
}
```

The method **PostData** gets new 10 items when ever we scroll to the bottom of the ListView.

The problem is, this works fine, for first 3-4 scrolls, and later i get the Exception and the new 10 items added are from the previous data(duplication).

Some times i even get this Exception:

```
Socket closed
```

in place of

```
Attempted read on closed stream
```

but i haven't used any **Sockets**, to try fixing it.

**Edit:**

Actually i have Log in every catch block, which prints the Exception. But i didn't add all those Logs in the question. The ones which i get in the LogCat are listed above.

I keep getting these lines in the Logcats info:

```
11-21 15:49:57.735: I/System.out(1034): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:36508]
11-21 15:49:57.735: I/System.out(1034): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:36508]
11-21 15:50:02.978: I/System.out(1034): [socket][3] connection /76.74.166.78:80(0)
11-21 15:50:03.010: I/System.out(1034): /76.74.166.78:80(0)
11-21 15:50:03.330: I/System.out(1034): Socket[addr=/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=33818]
11-21 15:50:03.331: I/System.out(1034): [socket][/192.168.1.6:33818]
11-21 15:50:03.341: I/System.out(1034): setSoSndTimeout:0
11-21 15:50:03.342: I/System.out(1034): setSendBufferSize:8096
11-21 15:50:04.164: I/System.out(1034): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:33818]
11-21 15:50:04.165: I/System.out(1034): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:33818]
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing in logcat. Since i am catching almost all possible exceptions. It wont crash but gives me wrong(previous) data. And the only Exception being caught in such cases is the 1 listed in the question

Comment: maybe you should start by verifying whether your server returns correct data every time the function is called. This will help in knowing whether error is in android app or server code.

Comment: The data sent from the server is correct. Moreover it works fine for the 1st 3-4 scrolls, and sometimes only for the 1st scroll. and later it gives this exception and if i continue scrolling it works fine sometime later and so on.

Comment: 1 thing which annoys me is the **Socket Close Exception**. I haven't used any socket in my application, still i get this Exception sometimes. Any idea of possible reasons??

Comment: take out all your try/catch blocks and let the exceptions happen. Then you can debug it properly. The approach you have now won't tell you what's wrong effectively if you catch all exceptions and pretend like they never happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ignore every possible exception, this kind of error is inevitable. A `try/catch` block in the middle of a method with more code after it is automatically suspect. Try catching, logging, and handling exceptions *properly,* by which I mean not continuing after they happen as though they hadn't happened.

Comment: Sorry. Actually i have Log in every catch block, which prints the Exception. But i didn't add all those Logs in the question.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc And you are still continuing beyond the catch {} blocks whether the exception happened or not. Your code is incorrectly structured. All the catch{} blocks should be at the end.

Comment: You mean the whole code must be in a single try block with all the catch blocks at the end?

Comment: No, @EJP, that practice tee's me to no end. Exceptions should be caught as early as possible and **dealt with appropriately**

Comment: @hd1 I fail to see why I should be interested in what 'tees you off'. What I am addressing here is concrete structural flaws in his code, i.e. code that proceeds after an exception as though it hadn't happened. Where you personally like to put catch blocks is your own business.

Comment: @EJP we are saying the exact same thing, sir... Exceptions should be caught as soon as possible and **dealt with appropriately**

Comment: @hd1 If we are saying the exact same thing, why did you start your comment with 'no'? What exactly are you talking about?